# Transform rotateY(180deg) not working on IE

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm using the transform: rotateY(180deg) to flip some text but it's not working on IE. I've read online that the 3d perspective doesn't work but I'm not too sure what that means for me.

**Update here is the page link https://www.freedmaninternational.com/new-about-us-test/**

```
-ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
/* -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); */
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
```

These don't seem to have an impact.

Here's the CSS

```css
.flip-card {
background-color: transparent;
perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
transition: transform 0.6s;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-back {
transform: rotateY(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 position: absolute;
bottom: 0%;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
top: -30%;
height: 100%;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-front h3 {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I need it to work on IE and across all browsers. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, the "-ms-transform: rotateY(180deg)" works well on IE 11, can you post the Enough code (include the related html elements) to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

transform is today well supported, and if you still want to use the prefix syntax for older browsers, they should be written first.

The unprefixed rule should be written last, browsers that do not support it  should not see it.

```css
span{
-ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);/* should be the last, so the browser uses the latest rule it understands */

}

/* center x,y the test in old browser and IE11, else use flex or grid*/
html {
height:100%;
width:100%;
display:table;
}
body {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
font-size:5vh
}
```

```html
<span>ROTATION IN IE ?</span>
```